# Count of combinations of values in rows across the entire table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using the following data in a table:

```
|   name |    d1 |     d2 |     d3 |     d4 |     d5 |     d6 |     d7 |     d8 |
|--------|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  matty | 116.7 |  17.88 |   16.1 |  9.731 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|   jana | 17.88 |  116.7 |  65.45 |   72.1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  chris |  72.1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| khaled | 9.731 |  116.7 |  17.88 |   53.1 |      2 |   85.2 | (null) | (null) |
|    "   |   "   |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |
|    n   |   "   |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |   "    |
```

how is it possible to identify the count of times that combination of values did appear amongst all rows in SQL?

> **The following is the output sample required:**
>
> 116.7, 17.88 (3)
>
> 116.7, 17.88, 9.731 (2)
>
> 72.1 (2)
>
> 16.1 (1)
>
> 65.45 (1)
>
> 53.1 (1)
>
> 2 (1)
>
> 85.2 (1)

If it is not possible with SQL, any alternative method could do it?

Comment: Alternative to sql? Where is this data coming from then?

Comment: What should happen if f.ex. `d1 = d2`? Is a `(d1, d2)` pair a valid combination in that case, or would it be just `(d1)`?

Comment: @pozs yes in such cases d1, d2 would be a valid combination, and the order in which the pair is set doesnt matter. As in, (d1, d2) = (d2, d1)

Comment: should not `9.731 (2)` be in results as well?..

Comment: Tsun It is in the result by the function create by @pozs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in PostgreSQL for combination calculation, but you can write a function for it, f.ex.:

```
create or replace function combinations(variadic anyarray)
  returns setof anyarray
  language sql
  immutable
  called on null input
as $func$
  with recursive e as (
      select *
      from   unnest($1) with ordinality u(e, o)
      where  e is not null
  ),
  r as (
      select distinct on (e) array[e] ea, array[o] oa
      from   e
    union all
      select distinct on (oea) oea, oa || o
      from   r, e, lateral (select array_agg(u order by u) oea from unnest(ea || e) u) l
      where  o <> all(oa)
  )
  select ea
  from   r
$func$;
```

With this function, you can write a query like:

```
select     combinations, count(*)
from       table_name
cross join combinations(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8)
group by   1
```

However, there will be a lot more combinations in your sample input than your sample output contains. (Maybe you just left them out to preserve space?)

http://rextester.com/NNVK84197

*Notes*:

- The function above uses a variable number of parameters, which is converted to a native PostgreSQL array (because of [`variadic`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)).
- It accepts any type of input, as long as they are all of the same type (because of [`anyarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC)). This is called poliformism. Also, because of `returns setof anyarray`, it will return a complete result set (multiple rows) of the same array type.
- `language sql` just simplifies the function body: it will not contain any advanced procedural language construct, like `IF` or `LOOP` anyway (`language plpgsql` can contain these).
- The [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) with `e` alias unwinds the data from the input array, but preserves the ordering/indexing information in the `o` field (see [`with ordinality`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)). This will be essential later, as we cannot use the values themselves to remove duplications (i.e. `(2, 2)` should be a valid combination, as you commented earlier). `NULL`s are discarded here.
- The recursive CTE with `r` alias (thus the `recursive` keyword after `with`) will accumulate every combination. It starts with every single value. Then in each step, it appends an element, with **another** ordinality (index) from the original set (see `where o <> all(oa)`). Because the elements order in a combination does not matter (as you commented), I ordered the element in a sub-query. Also, both of the recursive query parts use `distinct on (<combination>)` to remove any possible repetition, which can be happening when multiple elements have the same value.
- The solution query uses an implicit [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join to calculate every combinations, for every rows. This step will multiply your table's original rows as many times as combinations exists for them. Then, we just need to use `GROUP BY combinations` & `COUNT(*)` each of them.

Comment: This is it! You are the best!

Comment: Yes, i didnt include them to preserve space.
Can you please clarify how the function works?

Comment: @Dabbous updated with detailed description of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In below case I am not imagining different combination for `d1`,`d2`. If both are same, you will get one value with count of `2`.

So assuming that the number of columns are finite and fixed, then you can do it with help of union

**<kbd>[`Rextester Demo`](http://rextester.com/EFOI52636)</kbd>**

```
select concat(array_to_string(array_agg(col),',')   ,' (',  cnt ,')' ) as result
from 
(
    select col,count(*) cnt
    from 
    (   select d1 as col from table1
        union all 
        select d2 from table1
        union all
        select d3 from table1
         --similarly add other columns
    ) t
    where col is not null
    group by col
) t1
group by cnt
order by cnt desc;
```

Output

```
result 
--------------------------
17.88,116.7 (3) 
72.1,16.1,65.45,9.731 (1)
```

Else you have to create a procedure to get all the columns in a union and then do `group by` and `count` like above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this (you have to add to obtain combination for 4,5,6,7 and 8 values : I stopped at 3 values.)

```
    with CTE_001 as (
        SELECT name,D1 AS XVAL FROM mytable2 WHERE D1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,D2 FROM mytable2 WHERE D2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,D3 FROM mytable2 WHERE D3 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,D4 FROM mytable2 WHERE D4 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,D5 FROM mytable2 WHERE D5 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,D6 FROM mytable2 WHERE D6 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,D7 FROM mytable2 WHERE D7 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,D8 FROM mytable2 WHERE D8 IS NOT NULL
    )
    SELECT CONCAT(XVAL1, ', ', XVAL2) AS LOV, COUNT(*) AS RC 
    FROM(
     SELECT C1.NAME, C1.XVAL AS XVAL1, C2.XVAL AS XVAL2
        FROM CTE_001 C1 
        INNER JOIN CTE_001 C2 ON C1.NAME = C2.NAME
        WHERE C1.XVAL < C2.XVAL
        ) B 
        GROUP BY XVAL1, XVAL2
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(XVAL1, ', ' , XVAL2,', ', XVAL3), COUNT(*) AS RC 
    FROM(
    SELECT C1.NAME, C1.XVAL AS XVAL1, C2.XVAL AS XVAL2, C3.XVAL AS XVAL3
        FROM CTE_001 C1 
        INNER JOIN CTE_001 C2 O
N C1.NAME = C2.NAME
    INNER JOIN CTE_001 C3 ON C1.NAME = C3.NAME
    WHERE C1.XVAL < C2.XVAL  AND C1.XVAL < C3.XVAL AND C2.XVAL < C3.XVAL
    ) B
GROUP BY XVAL1, XVAL2, XVAL3
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Output:

```
    lov rc
1   17.880, 116.700 3
2   9.731, 116.700  2
3   9.731, 17.880   2
4   9.731, 17.880, 116.700  2
```